# How to customise JavaScript geolocation dialogue box with jQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-geolocation

Is it possible to customise the JavaScript geolocation authorisation dialogue box using jQuery UI dialog?

Answer (score 0):

No, because it's generated by the browser similar to an alert dialog.